# Running Access Function on remote machine with powerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, vbscript, vba

I have an access db set up with the following function in it:

```
Function testRun() As Boolean
    If 1 = 1 Then
        testRun = True
    End If
End Function
```

I then have a PowerShell script with this code it in:

```
$Access = New-Object -com "Access.Application"
$Access.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\script\Database11.accdb", $false)
$LASTEXITCODE = $Access.Run("testRun")
$Access.Quit()|Out-Null
Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

When I execute the powerShell script on the local machine it works fine, I get True returned, however if I use the invoke command to run it remotely on another machine I'm getting the following error:
[image]

My real script is more complicated, but I simplified my Access function to make sure that it wasn't the problem.  I've tried moving the location of my db around, it was originally on a network drive, but I then moved it to the C drive of the remote machine, I get the same error either way.  I also tried calling a VBScript to run the function and that too came back with an error.  I'm guessing it's some access security setting but I cannot figure out what it could be.  Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried specifying _projectname.procedurename_? For example, `"Project1.testRun"`.

Comment: Is WinRM enabled and configured on the remote machine?  -edit, searched for the HRESULT and landed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837754/call-routine-in-access-module-from-net)

Comment: @Bond the script will not run if I put the module name and then the function.

Comment: @user4317867 I can run other remote scripts on the machine, so unless their is a special setting to allow access functions to run I believe it's enabled.
I also have the access file in a trusted location, so I don't believe that is the problem.

Comment: Is this page at all related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518043/running-access-macro-in-powershell

Comment: @Heather did you see the page I mentioned in my comment?  There was talk about a security setting within Access that might be worth looking at.  [Here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837754/call-routine-in-access-module-from-net)